# Free Variables in a Reduced Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the relation between Column space, Null space, and Span to free variables? In other words if I'm given a matrix and I get it into echelon form or reduced echelon form, and there are free variables left over, what does that tell me about Column space, Null space, and Span?

Answer (score 2):

What do the free variables tell you about the **[rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28matrix_theory%29)** of the matrix?

Recall:

> The column rank of a matrix A is the maximum number of linearly independent column vectors of A. The row rank of a A is the maximum number of linearly independent row vectors of A. Equivalently, the column rank of A is the dimension of the column space of A, while the row rank of A is the dimension of the row space of A.
>
> A result of fundamental importance in linear algebra is that the column rank and the row rank are always equal. This number (i.e., the number of linearly independent rows or columns) is simply called the rank of A.

Hint: Use the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank-nullity_theorem) to draw some desired conclusions.

Comment: Sorry I'm only in an intro course I know nothing about rank.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still not making a connection. I think at this point I am mostly looking for confirmation of a null space, column space, or span through the existence of free variables if that is possible.

Comment: E.g. The existence of a free variable (row of zeros) in a matrix with $n$ rows and $n$ columns tells you that there are $n - 1$ linearly independent row vectors. This means the rank of the matrix is $n-1$: this also means there are $n - 1$ linearly independent column vectors (column space = n - 1). The dimension of the matrix being n, the rank nullity theorem tells you that the rank of the matrix + dimension of the nullspace of a matrix is equal to the dimension of the matrix. So nullspace = dimension - rank = 1, in this case.

Comment: See this part of the [entry on "rank"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28matrix_theory%29#Rank_from_row_echelon_forms) to see how rank relates to the number of **non-zero** rows in a row-echelon reduced matrix. Rank is simply a measure of how many non-zero rows remain.

Comment: @amWhy: hope the Op got it! ;-) +1

Comment: @Amzoti: I see that the OP had got it.

Comment: @BabakS.: The OP seems to have abandoned the thread, so I wasn't sure. Regards